# AirPrint does not work with Netgear router, HP LaserJet and macOS

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, router, printing, bonjour

I have a Netgear WNDR3700v5 router to which I have connected a MacBook Pro running macOS 10.12.6 and a HP LaserJet MFP 130FW printer.

The printer is set up to connect via AirPrint / Bonjour. Usually, I can print and scan just fine. However, after some time (days?), I cannot print anymore, neither can I scan. Using the *Bonjour Browser* I can verify that the printer cannot be detected from the Mac. What helps is basically restarting all my devices and reinstalling the printer.

When it *does* work, I see this listing in *Bonjour Browser*:

[image]

What I did to troubleshoot:

- I can always visit the printer's IP address, so it's not a general WiFi or connectivity issue.
- I have updated my router's firmware to the latest (V1.1.0.54_1.0.1)
- The same goes for the printer and macOS.
- Restarting the router seems to help, but it will stop working after a few days again.
- Enabling RIP v1 [as suggested here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070307100443478) did not work.
- Switching to a completely different WiFi router (my “dumb” ISP's modem) fixes the issue.

What can I do to fix this seemingly random problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the router—restarting it works. I guess I'll buy a new router.